# I want each individual drop down to be selected one by one and want all the data respectively

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to web scraping website data through python language that includes multiple drop-down's - static and dynamic through selenium but I want each commodity with respect to each state, each district, each market, date price, and arrival both. I've tried doing for a single commodity here's my code but I want all the things through any automation code or `for` loop or `while` loop that extracts all the data and converts that all data into **CSV** format
#help me!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://agmarknet.gov.in/')

time.sleep(3)

obj0 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ddlArrivalPrice"]/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(8)

obj1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ddlCommodity"]/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(10) 

obj2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ddlState"]/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(15)

obj3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ddlDistrict"]/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(15)

obj4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ddlMarket"]/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(8)

obj5 = driver.find_element(By.ID,'txtDate').click()
time.sleep(5)

obj6 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="CalendarExtender1_day_0_1"]').click()
time.sleep(6)

obj7 = driver.find_element(By.ID,'txtDateTo').click()
time.sleep(6)


obj8 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="CalendarExtender2_day_0_1"]').click()
time.sleep(6)

obj9 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btnGo"]').click()
time.sleep(5)

obj10 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cphBody_ButtonExcel"]').click()
time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Unless they're building the menus dynamically through Javascript, all of the options for a dropdown are present in the HTML whether the dropdown is displayed or not.

Comment: @Tim yes, but I know that but i want each of the data individually first select price then commodity then state,district,market,dates and go and after clicking on go the data which i get i want that of each drop down options

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each options of the selectors like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/chromedriver.exe')


driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://agmarknet.gov.in/')

def refind_element(locator,index):
    values = driver.find_element_by_id(locator).find_elements_by_tag_name("option")[index].text
    return values


time.sleep(6)
all_price_arrivals = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlArrivalPrice").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for i in range(0,len(all_price_arrivals)):
    selector_all_price_arrival = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlArrivalPrice'))    
    selector_all_price_arrival.select_by_index(i)    
    time.sleep(3)
    all_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlCommodity").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for j in range(1,(len(all_commodity))):
        selector_comodity = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlCommodity'))    
        selector_comodity.select_by_index(j)    
        time.sleep(3)
        all_state_options = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlState").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        for k in range(1,(len(all_state_options))):
            selector_state = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlState'))    
            selector_state.select_by_index(k)    
            time.sleep(3)
            all_district_options = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlDistrict").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
            for l in range(1,(len(all_district_options))):
                selector_district = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlDistrict'))
                selector_district.select_by_index(l)
                time.sleep(3)
                all_market_options = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlMarket").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
                for m in range(1,(len(all_market_options))):
                    selector_market = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlMarket'))
                    selector_market.select_by_index(m)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('Arrival/Price is: ' + refind_element('ddlArrivalPrice',i) + ', Commodity is: ' + refind_element('ddlCommodity',j) + ', State is: ' + refind_element('ddlState',k) + ', District is: ' + refind_element('ddlDistrict',l) + ', Market is: ' + refind_element('ddlMarket',m))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    #continue the test => select a date? and press go?
```

And the output is like:

[image]

Comment: Yes, then the date should be select automatically. So,I mean after every 24 hour the script should run and select the new date and then after pressing "GO" button.The, table will arrive and that table we have to fetch and store into ".csv" format like"Column-wise". Like this for every "Price-arrivals","Commodity","State","district","Market". and if it show's data not found then it would print "N.A" in the rows likewise process should be continue. @art_architect

Comment: can you please help me in this ! @art